# Find limit of modified geometric sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^3 q^k,$ where $\left| q\right| < 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I've been trying to find the limit of the infinite series

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^3 q^k, \quad \left| q\right| < 1$

I already determined that it converges using the ratio test, but I am at a loss when it comes to actually determine the limit.

I know how to calculate the limit of

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k q^k, \quad \left| q\right| < 1$

This is simple by derivation with respect to q applied to

$1 + q + q^2 + \ldots q^n = \frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}$

and then multiplying with $q$ and taking the limit. But this gets way too complicated when doing it three times. Is there a better way?

Comment: You can apply the same technique with the infinite series, which makes the calculation simpler.  Remember that a Taylor series can be differentiated term-by-term in the interval of convergence.

Comment: You can take the limit before differentiating, that makes it simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty k^nq^k = q\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^{n-1} \cdot kq^{k-1}  =  q\Big(\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^{n-1}  q^k\Big)' $$
So you can use recursion to calculate it.
\begin{align} \sum_{k=0}^\infty q^k &= \frac{1}{1-q} \\
\sum_{k=0}^\infty kq^k &= q\Big(\sum_{k=0}^\infty q^k\Big)' = q\Big(\frac{1}{1-q}\Big)' = \frac{q}{(1-q)^2} \\ 
\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2q^k &= q\Big(\sum_{k=0}^\infty kq^k\Big)' = q\Big(\frac{q}{(1-q)^2}\Big)' = \frac{q^2+q}{(1-q)^3} \\
\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^3q^k &= q\Big(\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2q^k\Big)' = q\Big(\frac{q^2+q}{(1-q)^3}\Big)' = \frac{q^3 + 4q^2 +q}{(1-q)^4}  \end{align}

Comment: This is genius!

Comment: Thank you a lot. I would have never come to the idea that I'm able to have the limit inside the derivation.

Comment: @Katharina: I do not recommend you anyhow switch limit and summation or integral or derivative, unless you know the precise conditions under which it can be done, and preferably understand the proofs as well. This is because the clearest understanding of what is really going on is via concrete bounds as shown in my answer.

Comment: @Katharina It's not always possible, but if you only deal with power series $\sum_n a_n (x-x_0)^n$, then inside the interval where the series is convergent it is allowed to interchange the sum with the differentiation or integration.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

$$k^3=k(k-1)(k-2)+3k(k-1)+k.$$
On the other hand,
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k q^k&= q\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kq^{k-1}=q\biggl(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} q^{k}\biggr)\vphantom{\Bigr)}^{\!'}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k(k-1) q^k&= q^2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k(k-1)q^{k-2}=q^2\biggl(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} q^{k}\biggr)\vphantom{\Bigr)}^{\!''}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k(k-1)(k-2) q^k&=\dots\dots
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

There are technical issues with using differentiation; it is a highly non-trivial fact (compared to the sum you want to evaluate) that you can differentiate a (convergent) power series term-wise. You can look up Taylor expansion (with remainder term) and its proof, but for now observe that there is a **simple elementary solution**:

> $q · \sum_{k=0}^n k^3 q^k = \sum_{k=0}^n k^3 q^{k+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (k-1)^3 q^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} (k-1)^3 q^k$.
>
> Thus $\sum_{k=0}^n k^3 q^k - q · \sum_{k=0}^n k^3 q^k = \sum_{k=0}^n (k^3-(k-1)^3) q^k - n^3 q^{n+1}$.
>
> Thus $(1-q) · \sum_{k=0}^n k^3 q^k = \sum_{k=0}^n (3k^2-3k+1) q^k - n^3 q^{n+1}$.

As you can see, we have reduced the degree of the polynomial part of each term in the series. I leave it to you to repeat the process, which would let you find the **closed-form** for $\sum_{k=0}^n k^3 q^k$, from which it is then easy to find $\lim_{n→∞} \sum_{k=0}^n k^3 q^k$ as desired.